# V$CONTAINERS only shows CDB root

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have created a common user `c##user` and it has been assigned the following permissions:

```
  GRANT CREATE SESSION TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SET CONTAINER TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SELECT ON V_\$DATABASE TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT FLASHBACK ANY TABLE TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SELECT ANY TRANSACTION TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT LOGMINING TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT CREATE TABLE TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT ALTER ANY TABLE TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT LOCK ANY TABLE TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_LOGMNR TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_LOGMNR_D TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SELECT ON V_\$LOGMNR_LOGS TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SELECT ON V_\$LOGMNR_CONTENTS TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SELECT ON V_\$LOGFILE TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SELECT ON V_\$ARCHIVED_LOG TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
  GRANT SELECT ON V_\$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS TO c##user CONTAINER=ALL;
```

But yet when I connect with this user to the CDB$ROOT and run `SELECT * FROM V$CONTAINERS` the only row that is returned is the one for the `CDB$ROOT` but there is an `ORCLPDB1` that is open and available.  If I execute:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=ORCLPDB1;
SELECT * FROM V$CONTAINERS;
```

Then the query only returns information for `ORCLPDB1` as the documentation says it should.  But why when I am connected to the CDB root and I run the same query against `V$CONTAINERS` do I not see any PDBs?

It's my understaning that the common user should see `ORCLPDB1` in the `V$CONTAINERS` view only when I am connected to the `CDB$ROOT` but that's not happening.  Is there a permission problem here that I don't see?

**UPDATE**

It looks like the common user must be explicitly given access to container data using the following executed by an administrator for the `V$CONTAINERS` view to return results besides the current container.

```
ALTER USER c##user SET CONTAINER_DATA=(CDB$ROOT,ORCLPDB1) CONTAINER=CURRENT;
```

Is that the expected way to handle this?

Comment: What about v$pdbs ? What information it is showing ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected behavior of the system.

As per Oracle documentation:

> Extended data-linked Oracle-supplied data dictionary objects
>
> This type of object stores data pertaining to the CDB root, as well as
> data pertaining to individual PDBs.
>
> When this type of object is queried from the CDB root, only data
> pertaining to the CDB root is returned.

So `v$container` is an extended data objects as it contains data about both root as well as other PDBs and hence by default it will only show data about the root.

```
ALTER USER c##user SET CONTAINER_DATA=(CDB$ROOT,ORCLPDB1) CONTAINER=CURRENT;
```

Above alter will enable system to show data about ORCLPDB1 PDB as well and if you again alter it as below it will show data of ROOT only

```
ALTER USER c##user SET CONTAINER_DATA=(CDB$ROOT) CONTAINER=CURRENT;
```